# Associating turtles and links through attributes

Tags: netlogo

I have a road network consisting of directed links between nodes.  Cars drive over the network on paths that are randomly generated at setup but remain fixed for the duration of travel.  I want to count the number of cars on any given link:

```
breed [cars car]
breed [road_nodes road_node]
directed-link-breed [road_segments road_segment]

cars-own [current-road-segment] 
road-segments-own [number-cars-here]
```

I'd like the value of number-cars-here for road_segment x y to be number of cars with current-road-segment = "road_segment x y".  Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to count them all at one go:

```
to count-cars ;;observer proc
  ask road_segments [set number-cars-here 0]
  ask cars [
    ask current-road-segment [
      set number-cars-here (number-cars-here + 1)
    ]
  ]
end
```